# Solution to Fermat Point optimization problem.

Tags: nonlinear-optimization

There are 3 points in a plane $(x_1,y_1)$,$(x_2,y_2)$,$(x_3,y_3)$.
I am trying to find a solution to the unconstrained minimization problem which is the point $(a,b)$ of least distance between the 3.

$\min F(a,b) = \sum_{i=1}^3 \sqrt{(a-x_i)^2+(b-y_i)^2}$

I am stuck on the first order conditions.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_mean

Comment: Thanks although I was hoping for an explicit solution in terms of a and b.